# How to prevent console from being displayed when using VLC's dummy interface

Tags: windows, node.js, subprocess, vlc, child-process

I'm trying to launch VLC in "dummy" mode from a Node.js server script, however using `child_process.spawn('vlc',['-I dummy'])` produces a new console window for VLC's output when using Windows. Is there a way to prevent this happening and force all stdout though the stdout ReadableStream so no "popup windows" occur?

**EDIT**: This problem had nothing to do with node.js, it was simply the way I was calling it and VLC's behaviour. The solution is below.

Thanks.

Comment: I've noticed that -I telnet doesn't pop up the console, so I'll use this instead.

Comment: However, the telnet interface is useless - I'd prefer to use the RC interface, but that has the same problem as dummy with a new window - and worse the stdin stdout doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a solution for the specific problem:

VLC has a command line option to surpress this window --*-quiet where * is the interface.

e.g. For the dummy interface, use

```
child_process.spawn('vlc',['-I dummy','--dummy-quiet'])
```

For the rc interface, use

```
child_process.spawn('vlc',['-I rc','--rc-quiet'])
```

Answer (score 1):

I would like to complement Adam M-W answer.

> ***VLC has a command line option to suppress this window --*-quiet where * is the interface.***
>
> e.g. For the dummy interface, use
>
> child_process.spawn('**vlc**',['**-I dummy**','**--dummy-quiet**']) For the rc
>   interface, use
>
> child_process.spawn('**vlc**',['**-I rc**','**--rc-quiet**'])
>
> > answered Jun 13 '11 at 14:12
> >     Adam M-W

*at least on my system,* VLC now sends its messages to **stdError**, so this is the channel which needs to be monitored.

My interface is with Qt , QtProcess and these are the options that worked for me.

Using ***MergedChannels*** and reading **stdOut**.

```
m_proc->setProcessChannelMode(QProcess::MergedChannels);
connect (m_proc,SIGNAL(readyReadStandardOutput()),
           this, SLOT(readyRead()));

void ReDirVLC::readyRead(){
    if (!m_proc) return;
    qDebug()<<m_proc->readAllStandardOutput() << endl;
}
```

Using ***SeparateChannels*** and reading **stdError**

```
m_proc->setProcessChannelMode(QProcess::SeparateChannels);
connect (m_proc,SIGNAL(readyReadStandardError()),
           this, SLOT(readyRead()));

void ReDirVLC::readyRead(){
    if (!m_proc) return;
    qDebug()<<m_proc->readAllStandardError() << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could run the process with `child_process.spawn('start', ['/b', 'vlc', '-I dummy'])` instead?