# WIndows: subprocess making new console window, losing stdin/out

Tags: python, windows, stdin, stdio, filehandle

I'm using Windows Vista and Python 2.7.2, but answers needn't be in Python.

So I can start and interact with a subprocesses stdin/stdout normally (using python), for command-line programs such as `dir'.

- however -

the program I now want to call likes to make a new console window for itself on Windows (not curses), with new handles, even when run from a pre-existing cmd.exe window. (Odd, as it's the "remote control" interface of VLC.) Is there any way of either:

1. getting the handles for the process-made console's stdin/out; or
2. getting the new shell to run within the old (like invoking bash from within bash)?

Failing that, so that I can hack the subprocesses' code, how would a new console be set up in Windows and in/output transferred?

Edit:
I.e.

```
>>> p = Popen(args=['vlc','-I','rc'],stdin=PIPE,stdout=PIPE)
# [New console appears with text, asking for commands]
>>> p.stdin.write("quit\r\n")
Traceback:
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IOError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
>>> p.stdout.readline()
''
>>> p.stdout.readline()
''
# [...]
```

But the new console window that comes up doesn't accept keyboard input either.

Whereas normally:

```
>>> p = Popen(args=['cmd'],stdin=PIPE,stdout=PIPE)
>>> p.stdin.write("dir\r\n")
>>> p.stdin.flush()
>>> p.stdout.readline() #Don't just do this IRL, may block.
'Microsoft Windows [Version...
```

Comment: @eryksun Yes, I'm running `vlc -I rc`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't gotten the rc interface to work with a piped stdin/stdout on Windows; I get `IOError` at all attempts to `communicate` or write directly to `stdin`. There's an option `--rc-fake-tty` that lets the rc interface be scripted on Linux, but it's not available in Windows -- at least not in my somewhat dated version of VLC (1.1.4). Using the socket interface, on the other hand, seems to work fine.

The structure assigned to the `startupinfo` option -- and used by the Win32 `CreateProcess` function -- can be configured to hide a process window. However, for the VLC rc console, I think it's simpler to use the existing `--rc-quiet` option. In general, here's how to configure `startupinfo` to hide a process window:

```
startupinfo = subprocess.STARTUPINFO()
startupinfo.dwFlags |= subprocess.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW
subprocess.Popen(cmd, startupinfo=startupinfo)
```

Just to be complete -- in case using pipes is failing on your system too -- here's a little demo I cooked up using the `--rc-host` option to communicate using a socket. It also uses `--rc-quiet` to hide the console. This just prints the help and quits. I haven't tested anything else. I checked that it works in Python versions 2.7.2 and 3.2.2. (I know you didn't ask for this, but maybe it will be useful to you nonetheless.)

```
import socket
import subprocess
from select import select

try:
    import winreg
except ImportError:
    import _winreg as winreg

def _get_vlc_path():
    views = [(winreg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER, 0),
             (winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, winreg.KEY_WOW64_64KEY),
             (winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, winreg.KEY_WOW64_32KEY)]
    subkey = r'Software\VideoLAN\VLC'
    access = winreg.KEY_QUERY_VALUE
    for hroot, flag in views:
        try:
            with winreg.OpenKey(hroot, subkey, 0, access | flag) as hkey:
                value, type_id = winreg.QueryValueEx(hkey, None)
                if type_id == winreg.REG_SZ:
                    return value
        except WindowsError:
            pass
    raise SystemExit("Error: VLC not found.")

g_vlc_path = _get_vlc_path()

def send_command(sock, cmd, get_result=False):
    try:
        cmd = (cmd + '\n').encode('ascii')
    except AttributeError:
        cmd += b'\n'
    sent = total = sock.send(cmd)
    while total < len(cmd):
        sent = sock.send(cmd[total:])
        if sent == 0:
            raise socket.error('Socket connection broken.')
        total += sent
    if get_result:
        return receive_result(sock)

def receive_result(sock):
    data = bytearray()
    sock.setblocking(0)
    while select([sock], [], [], 1.0)[0]:
        chunk = sock.recv(1024)
        if chunk == b'': 
            raise socket.error('Socket connection broken.')
        data.extend(chunk)
    sock.setblocking(1)
    return data.decode('utf-8')

def main(address, port):
    import time
    rc_host = '{0}:{1}'.format(address, port)
    vlc = subprocess.Popen([g_vlc_path, '-I', 'rc', '--rc-host', rc_host, 
                            '--rc-quiet'])
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    try:
        sock.connect((address, port))
        help_msg = send_command(sock, 'help', True)
        print(help_msg)
        send_command(sock, 'quit')
    except socket.error as e:
        exit("Error: " + e.args[0])
    finally:
        sock.close()
        time.sleep(0.5)
        if vlc.poll() is None:
            vlc.terminate()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main('localhost', 12345)
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for the info and the socket solution, which is working very well. The code was useful. I wasn't expecting such a specific answer, and thought I was at a dead end. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

With reference to monitoring the stdOut which appears in the new Spawned Console Window.

Here´s [another question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6001034/how-to-prevent-console-from-being-displayed-when-using-vlcs-dummy-interface/) that solves the problem.

In summary (as answered by [Adam M-W](https://stackoverflow.com/users/108302/adam-m-w) ):

- Suppress the new spawned console by launching vlc in quiet mode `--intf=dummy --dummy-quiet` or `--intf=rc --rc-quiet`.
- Monitor **stdErr** of launched process

*Note: As for stdIn commands for the rc interface, the `--rc-host` solution is described by [eryksun´s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8111621/2078851)*