# spawn a command line operation in nodejs without opening console

Tags: node.js, child-process, spawn

I need to execute a command line operation from nodejs program. But I don't want to open console. I need to get result back to a variable. sync-exec module is helping to get result back but it keeps open a console for process execution.

I am sharing small bit of code.

```
       var execSync = require('sync-exec');
       var npmGlobalPath = execSync('npm config get prefix');
       console.log(npmGlobalPath);
```

one more thing I want to share. This was happening when I already spawned a child process from parent. Now this code is in child process.

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: Are you working with Windows? If so see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6001034/how-to-prevent-console-from-being-displayed-when-using-vlcs-dummy-interface

Comment: @vincent it is vlc specific thing. not associated with nodejs